# Why doesn't array() and [] behave the same in this example

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code as an example of what I can't fully understand.
So array() and [] are the exact same thing right? Some saying [] might be slightly faster than array(), but thats not the topic of this question right now.

Here is the code:

```
function userLogin( $user, $return = null ) {

    [$user['username'],$user['password']] = [$user[0],$user[1]];

    switch ($return) {

        case 1:
            return $user['username'];

        case 2:
            return $user['password'];

        default:
            return $user['username'].":".$user['password'];

    }

}

print userLogin(['admin','secretkey']);
```

The code does not play any significant role and I know, because I'm putting this out there as an example.
The topic of this question is the third line in the code, I'm using short array syntax to assign some values to the username and password inside the array, but the problem happens when I try to do the same to make the code compliant with PHP 5.3 and less versions.

```
array($user['username'], $user['password']) = array($user[0], $user[1]);
```

If array() and [] are the same, why doesn't array() work in this particular scenario?

---

### Console output

Short array syntax:

```
admin:secretkey
```

Regular array() function:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\Users\Soricy\Desktop\fn.userLogin.php on line 3
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\Users\Soricy\Desktop\fn.userLogin.php on line 3
```

### Edit 1:

I'm fully aware of using:

```
$user = array(
    'username' => $user[0],
    'password' => $user[1]
);
```

But I sometimes want to do it inline.

---

### So...

Have I possibly missed something from the [PHP Documentation about Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) and if so, what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing things up.

Array-creation syntax is the following:

```php
$a = array(1,2,3);
$b = [1,2,3];
$a === $b; //true
```

-- in this case `array()` and `[]` are completely equal.

Your example:

```php
[$user['username'],$user['password']] = [$user[0],$user[1]];
```

-- is called [Symmetric array destructuring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring) which's been introduced in PHP 7.1 as a replacement for `list()`. It can not be replaced with `array()` but can be replaced with `list()` in older versions.

Comment: So it means for older versions of PHP I should rely on list() if I want the desired behaviour?

Comment: @M.aHacker, correct. Or just refuse from such tricky assignment ;)